# couchdb update handler for PUT for JSON query param not working

Tags: python, curl, couchdb, python-requests

I am working on update handlers with couchdb and am facing this strange problem:

Here goes my update handler:

```
"updates": {
       "temp": "function(doc, req) {var inc_amount =JSON.parse(req.query.amount);doc[1]=inc_amount;return [doc, JSON.stringify(inc_amount) + JSON.stringify({\"STATUS\": \"message\"})];}"
   },
```

Here is my couchdb document:

```
{
   "_id": "my_doc",
   "_rev": "51-62e63d1ba46abbe6678a6c57f5500782"
}
```

I want to update this document with the value of the `amount` query parameter. Here is how I'm able to do it using command line (curl basically):

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/db/_design/designdoc/_update/temp/my_doc?amount='\{"a":\{"b":"c"\}\}'
```

This command works perfectly for me. But, as this update would be called by a python code, I dont want a separate `subprocess` for `curl` for doing this stuff. Rather, I'm looking for a pythonic solution. Here is what I have tried to achieve using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module:

```
>>> import json
>>> d={'a':{'b':'c'}}
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 'c'}}
>>> s=json.dumps(d)
>>> s
'{"a": {"b": "c"}}'
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.put('http://localhost:5984/file_status_collector/_design/reportsDesignDoc/_update/temp/my_doc', data = {'amount': s})
>>> r.status_code
500
>>> r.text
u'{"error":"render_error","reason":"function raised error: (new SyntaxError(\\"JSON.parse\\", \\"/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js\\", 481)) \\nstacktrace: SyntaxError(\\"JSON.parse\\")@:0\\n(\\"undefined\\")@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:481\\n([object Object],[object Object])@:0\\napply([object Object],[object Array])@:0\\nrunUpdate(function (doc, req) {var inc_amount = JSON.parse(req.query.amount);doc[1] = inc_amount;return [doc, JSON.stringify(inc_amount) + JSON.stringify({STATUS:\\"message\\"})];},[object Object],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:952\\n(function (doc, req) {var inc_amount = JSON.parse(req.query.amount);doc[1] = inc_amount;return [doc, JSON.stringify(inc_amount) + JSON.stringify({STATUS:\\"message\\"})];},[object Object],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1021\\napply(null,[object Array])@:0\\n(\\"_design/reportsDesignDoc\\",[object Array],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1492\\napply(null,[object Array])@:0\\n()@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1535\\n@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1546\\n"}\n'
```

Here I faced a problem. So, I thought of changing the json string `s` into the format that I was giving to curl:

```
>>> s=s.replace(' ','').replace('{','\{').replace('}','\}')
>>> s
'\\{"a":\\{"b":"c"\\}\\}'
>>> print s
\{"a":\{"b":"c"\}\}
>>> r=requests.put('http://localhost:5984/file_status_collector/_design/reportsDesignDoc/_update/temp/my_doc', data = {'amount': s})
>>> r.status_code
500
>>> r.text
u'{"error":"render_error","reason":"function raised error: (new SyntaxError(\\"JSON.parse\\", \\"/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js\\", 481)) \\nstacktrace: SyntaxError(\\"JSON.parse\\")@:0\\n(\\"undefined\\")@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:481\\n([object Object],[object Object])@:0\\napply([object Object],[object Array])@:0\\nrunUpdate(function (doc, req) {var inc_amount = JSON.parse(req.query.amount);doc[1] = inc_amount;return [doc, JSON.stringify(inc_amount) + JSON.stringify({STATUS:\\"message\\"})];},[object Object],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:952\\n(function (doc, req) {var inc_amount = JSON.parse(req.query.amount);doc[1] = inc_amount;return [doc, JSON.stringify(inc_amount) + JSON.stringify({STATUS:\\"message\\"})];},[object Object],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1021\\napply(null,[object Array])@:0\\n(\\"_design/reportsDesignDoc\\",[object Array],[object Array])@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1492\\napply(null,[object Array])@:0\\n()@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1535\\n@/opt/local/share/couchdb/server/main.js:1546\\n"}\n'
```

Still, didn't help and now, I have laid down my arms. No idea how I should do it in a pythonic way. Definitely need your help here. Could you please help me in the following question:

1. Am I using the json in `requests.put` correctly? Can `requests.put` handle such requests? If yes, please correct my way of implementing.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `requests`, sadly, but there is a [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) if you're desperate for an answer. Worst case, the code is open source, and may have an answer, even if it isn't the one you're looking for.

Comment: You should look at the request generated by the python code with wireshark and compare it to the request curl generates.